# Show that, for any $n\in \mathbb N^*$, we have $k_{n+1} - k_n \in \{0,1\}.$

Tags: combinatorics

**The question**

For any nonzero natural number $n$, we define the set $M_n =
\{a \in N | [ \sqrt{n^2+2na} ]= n + a - 1\}$, where $[x]$ represents the integer part of the real number x. We denote by $k_n$ the cardinality of the set $M_n$.

a) Show that, for any n ∈ N*, we have $k_{n+1} - k_n \in {0;1}.$

b) Prove that there exists an infinity of numbers $n ∈ N*$, for which
$k_n=k_{n+1}$

c) Show that there is an infinity of numbers $n ∈ N*$, for which $k_n+1=k_{n+1}$

**The idea**

$M_n =\{ a \in N | [ \sqrt{n^2+2na} ]= n + a - 1\}$

$n+a-1 \leq \sqrt{n^2+2na}|()^2 => a^2-2a+1\leq 2n => (a-1)^2\leq 2n$

$M_{n+1} =\{ b \in N | [ \sqrt{(n+1)^2+2(n+1)b} ]= n + b\}$

$n+b \leq \sqrt{(n+1)^2+2(n+1)b}|()^2 => b^2\leq 2n+1+2b => (b-1)^2 \leq 2n+2=2(n+1)$

we have to show that $b$ has the same number of solutions as $a$ or one more.

I don't know what to do forward. I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: I can't tell from that work.  Have you shown that $M_n = \{a \in \mathbb{N} \mid (a-1)^2 \leq 2n\}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, this is what I've shown.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes... sorry, its a misspelling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done IMO most part of the work, with a few technical details missing and a relatively straightforward argument missing at the end to get at the subproblem a) and then b) and c).

As has been alluded to in the comments, the intermmediate goal is to show that

$$M_n = \{a \in \mathbb N\,|\, a > 0, (a-1)^2 \le 2n\}. \label{eq1} \tag{1}$$

You arrived at $(a-1)^2 \le 2n$ yourself, by starting with $n+a-1 \le \sqrt{n^2+2an}$ and then squaring. Note that squaring is not usually an equivalent transformation. It's only an implication (as you noted), so when you arrived at $(a-1)^2 \le 2n$ it only means that $M_n \subseteq \{a \in \mathbb N\,|\, (a-1)^2 \le 2n\}$, because you don't know if you got additional spurious solutions.

The good news is that in this case the transformation is equivalent, because you can prove from the initial assumptions ($a\ge 0, n \ge 1$) that both $n+a-1 \ge 0$ and $n^2+2an \ge 0$.

But we still only have $M_n \subseteq \{a \in \mathbb N\,|\, (a-1)^2 \le 2n\}$, because you forgot the other part of what $n+a-1 = \lfloor \sqrt{n^2+2an} \rfloor$ means, which is $\sqrt{n^2+2an} < (n+a-1) + 1 = n+a$. This can be equivalently transformed by squaring to $0 < a^2$, which is equivalent to $a > 0$ considering $a  \in \mathbb N$.

Since $n+a-1$ is an integer, both inequalities together are equivalent to $n+a-1 = \lfloor \sqrt{n^2+2an} \rfloor$, so **now** this proves \eqref{eq1}.

So what is the final argument that you are missing? First, $M_n \subseteq M_{n+1}$ should be easy to see, and also that
$$M_{n+1} - M_n = \{a \in \mathbb N\,|\, a > 0, (a-1)^2 \in \{2n+1, 2n+2\}\} \label{eq2} \tag{2}$$

That already means $k_{n+1} - k_n \in \{0,1,2\}$. The difference being $2$ would mean that both $2n+1$ and $2n+2$ are square numbers. Two consecutive integers can both be squares only for $0$ and $1$, but in our example the smaller of the 2 numbers must be odd. This solves a) and \eqref{eq2} should also make it possible to find the infinite number of values for $n$ that fulfill b) and c).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand evrything except the fact why the differece of the cardinals cant be 2. May i ask how i demonstrate it?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU I did. Is that OK so? I can go into more detail, but it should be more or less obvious that the difference between one square number and the next increases and a small difference like $1$ can only occur at the very beginning.

Comment: yesss..thank you...now i understand...and what should i do for the b) and c) ....i never knew how to demonatrate that there is an infinity of values

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Think about examples of $n$ for which the set $\{2n+1,2n+2\}$ does contain no square number. Can you find many/infinitely many? The same for when this set contains exactly 1 square number?

Comment: but can we demonstrate something just by ,,thinking" and observing that are infinitely values?

Comment: No, you try things out, observe a pattern and then try to generalize it.  IMO this is a really, really simple thing to at least try in this case. Maybe start with the case c), that may be simpler to devise a pattern.

Comment: For c) we already showed that 2n+1 and 2n+2 cant be both perfect squares, so at most just one of them is a perfect square and the other no. If so, we can say that are an infinitely perfect squares that have the form 2n+2 and for sure 2n+1 wouldn't be perfect square. Is it ok to justify it as this?

Comment: Yes, that works. You can find inifintely many examples that make $2n+1$ a square and also inifnitely many examples that make $2n+2$ a square.

Comment: And for b) we can say that there are infinite examples that make 2n and 2n+3 or greater number  both consecutive perfect square

Comment: That's unclear to me. I'd argue that $4k^2$ is a square, so choosing $n=2k^2$ makes $2n+1=4k^2+1$ and $2n+2 = 4^k+2$ non-squares (both come "to early" after a square to be squares again)